# How to break this line properly to match PEP 8 style guide?

Tags: python, pep8

```
training_data_all, test_data_all, feature_cols_all = divide_data('../data/feature.csv', training_ratio)
training_data_without_sports, test_data_without_sports, feature_cols_all = divide_data('../data/feature_without_sports.csv', training_ratio)
```

The first line can be broken on the part where the parenthesis begins, but the second line couldn't be broken in the same way.

I think it will be best to break both lines on parts where the `=` signs begin, but I couldn't find the way to break on `=` sign from the PEP8 documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place where redundant parentheses can help!-)

```
training_data_without_sports, test_data_without_sports, feature_cols_all = (
    divide_data('../data/feature_without_sports.csv', training_ratio))
```

(although, variable names of more sensible lengths would make your code **much** more readable!-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the line continuation suggestions given by the other answers is to separate the function call from the tuple unpacking (by using temporary variables):

```
feature_data = divide_data('../data/feature.csv', training_ratio)
training_data_all, test_data_all, feature_cols_all = feature data

nonsport_data = divide_data('../data/feature_without_sports.csv', training_ratio)
training_data_without_sports, test_data_without_sports, feature_cols_all = nonsport_data
```

The last line is still a bit long, that's simply a product of using such long variable names.